# how to convert numeric type to "seconds" in R

Tags: r, time-series, type-conversion, data-conversion

I want to create a Time Series data frame by doing this:

```
x <- xts(data$length,data$Time.Elapsed)
```

Then, I got a warning message:

```
Error in xts(data$length, data$Time.Elapsed) : 
  order.by requires an appropriate time-based object
```

So, I was thinking the problem is my "Time.Elapsed" is numeric data. Then I want to convert the data type of "Time.Elapsed", how can I achieve that?

```
>data$Time Elapsed
    Time Elapsed
    0
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
```

I want to create a time series data frame, so I need to have a time-based object in R. Here, "Time Elapsed" is a numeric variable (those numbers represent seconds); how can I convert it to time type "seconds"?  I searched the Data-time conversion function, like: `as.POSIX* {base}` But I don't think this function suits my case. Anyone can help me about this? Thank you very much!

Comment: @jogo Thank you, I already edited my question. Those numbers represent "seconds", but the data type is numeric, I want to change the data type to real "seconds", thus I can create my time series data frame.

Comment: Why would you want to convert them to seconds class (which does not exist in R btw).

Comment: @DavidArenburg I edited my question, Thank you for your help.The reason why I want to do this is I want to create a Time Series data frame.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I saw soneone using xts(DF$Close, as.Date(DF$Date, format='%m/%d/%Y') in this website.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `xts` but `Date` is a valid class in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're not going low-level enough on this.  `xts` provides some convenience functions to help determine if you can convert something to `xts` or not.

```
xtsible(data) #Will probably tell you it fails with your current setup.
```

`xts` builds on `zoo`, and `zoo` is a bit more flexible though harder to work with.

```
library(zoo)
zooData <- zoo(data$length, data$Time.Elapsed)
xtsible(zooData) #Will probably tell you it's ok, but probably doesn't matter since
                 #most/all of xts's functions work on zoo objects.
xtsData <- xts(zooData)
```

Comment: Both xtsible(data) and xtsible(zooData) tell me "False". Do you know how can I solve this problem to create a Time series data frame? My next step is to do DTW, so I have to use a time series data frame.

Comment: Just use zooData then.  Like I mention above, pretty much all of the xts functions also work on zoo objects.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! I never heard zoo data before, so it can substitute "Time Series" ?

Comment: The `zoo` package also deals with Time Series data and the `xts` package builds on top of what `zoo` and a few other packages provide.  I highly recommend looking at the vignettes for both `zoo` and `xts` so you better understand how they differ and how they work together.

Answer (score 0):

```
require(lubridate)    
x <- as.POSIXct(strptime(data$Time.Elapsed, format = "%S"))
as.duration(x)
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: You may not need the third line of code.  I am not sure what format you want it in the end.  If you don't need the third line, then you don't need the lubridate package either.

Comment: y <- as.POSIXct(strptime(data$Time.Elapsed, format = "%S"))
x <- xts(data$length,y)        Here, X is Time Series data Frame?

Comment: I got wrong message after I run as.duration(x): Error in .setupMethodsTables(fdef, initialize = TRUE) : 
  no slot of name "group" for this object of class "derivedDefaultMethod"

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing.  The `xts` method is for the answer below.  Did you mean to do this instead?

    `y <- as.POSIXct(strptime(data$Time.Elapsed, format = "%S"))`
    `x <- data.frame(data$length,y)`

Comment: @ Reuben Mathew I am trying to create a Time Series data frame.